# Recode multiple columns based in different conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to recode multiple columns in my data based on different conditions. I put a sample of my data:

```
data_test <- structure(list(county = c("algarrobo", "alhue", "alto del carmen","ancud", "andacollo", "angol", "antofagasta", "yumbel", "yungay","zapallar"), 
year = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001,2016, 2016, 2016),             
ruling = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
adjacent_county1 = c("el quisco", "san pedro", "tierra amarilla","maullin", "coquimbo", "nacimiento", "mejillones", "cabrero","pemuco", "papudo"), 
adjacent_county2 = c("casablanca", "melipilla","vallenar", "dalcahue", "la serena", "renaico", "sierra gorda","quillon", "pinto", "la ligua"), 
adjacent_county3 = c(NA,"paine", "la higuera", "quemchi", "vicuna", "collipulli","san pedro de atacama", "florida", "antuco", "nogales"),
adjacent_county4 = c(NA, "mostazal", "vicuna", NA, "rio hurtado","ercilla", "taltal", "hualqui", "tucapel", "puchuncavi"),
adjacent_county5 = c(NA, "graneros", NA, NA, NA, "los sauces","diego de almagro", "san rosendo", "los angeles", NA), 
adjacent_county6 = c(NA,"rancagua", NA, NA, NA, "canete", NA, "laja", "cabrero",NA), 
adjacent_county7 = c(NA, "donihue", NA, NA, NA, "puren",NA, "los angeles", NA, NA), 
adjacent_county8 = c(NA, "coltauco",NA, NA, NA, "los alamos", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
adjacent_county9 = c(NA,"las cabras", NA, NA, NA, "curanilahue", NA, NA, NA, NA),
adjacent_county10 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
adjacent_county11 = c(NA_character_,NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,NA_character_)), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For example, I have `Algarrobo` county in the year 2001 with ruling = 0. I need to recode all `Algarrobo`s appearing in the next columns as 1, but only on the 2001 year. And the same for the next counties in the data frame. I am very complicated about this problem because I thought about possible solutions but they are very unelegant and problematic for all the possible combinations I have to do. For example:

```
data_test <- data_test %>% map_at(c("adjacent_county1", "adjacent_county2", 
  "adjacent_county3"),  function(x) {recode(x, "algarrobo" = "0")}) %>% bind_rows()
```

And, furthermore, I can't specify the year in this chunk of code.

Thanks,

Comment: Please check your dput structure.  It is not complete

Comment: Thanks! I already edit the post to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your desired end result is here however using `dplyr::gather` to have a single column for `adjacent_counties` may make it easier rather than the current data structure. Using `dplyr::case_when` then will help with recoding